# VBA fails to find a file

Tags: vba

I have a VBA script used to process Word documents. The first thing the program does is to create an index of the documents in a defined set of folders. It then goes through the list processing each of the indexed documents.

The problem I am having is that it will sometimes decide that a particular document cannot be found, even though it previously indexed the document and a quick spot check shows the document to be in the correct place.

Can anyone shed some light on why VBA should display this behaviour?

The script is using the `Dir$` function to index the files, and the `Documents.Open` function to open each word document for processing.

Sample code:

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory (folderName)
inputFileName = Dir$(folderName & "*.doc")
Do While inputFileName <> ""
    ... call various functions here ...
    inputFileName = Dir$
Loop
```

One of the functions called in the block has the following line:

```
Set currentDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=docFileName, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
```

This is the point at which the code is failing.

Comment: someone accessing the file.....?

Comment: Is there a specific error it gives or does it skip it silently?

Comment: Very long path+ filenames may be also the cause

Comment: What method/command/function are you using to determine that that the document 'cannot be found'? Give an example of your failing code

Comment: @Mitch: No one else is accessing the files

Comment: @Nick: it is giving error 5174 - File could not be found

Comment: @smirkingman: I have on error goto x that sends errors to a point where I log them to a text file. Have now added example code.

Comment: @belisarius: The file names are not very long.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most annoying things I have found is that recent files links are returned as the files themselves with Dir. You can use the FileSystemObject to check the file type.

Comment: The documents I am opening from my code have never been opened on my computer before, so they cannot show as recent file links.

Answer (score 0):

I copy/paste your code and it works correctly.

However, it leaves all the files open (and hidden), and when you run it in another directory, additional files are opened and added to the open projects (take a look in the VBA editor).

My only guess is that after a while you're hitting the maximum allowable number of open files.

Try adding

```
currentdoc.Close
```

just before

```
inputFileName = Dir$
```

Comment: Sorry smirkingman, it did not occur to me to mention that I do currentDoc.Close in the same function where I do currentDoc.Open. I guess in my head it seemed too obvious to mention. The code does work correctly most of the time, it is just now and then it randomly decides that a particular document does not exist, even though it quite clearly does.

Answer (score 0):

A few reasons, some duplicated from other answers:

- If the path+ filename is long enough ... (you already answered in a comment)
- If you are writing new files to same directory, Dir$ may get corrupted (happened to me)
- If you have filenames with non-std chars (ex. "#")
- Files locked by other processes
- Files deleted while the macro is running

You may also try this code ...

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FileExists(file) Then ....
```

First enable the Microsoft Scripting reference in the VBE